# R ggplot: stacked barplots go beyond values

Tags: r, ggplot2

In some cases, stacked barplots create bars that go beyond values.

Here is a reproducible example showing the issue:

```
# creating some dataframe for the example
eg <- matrix(nrow=4, ncol=3)
eg[,1] <- c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b')
eg[,2] <- c('catA', 'catA', 'catB', 'catB')
eg[,3] <- c(0.7, 0.3, 0.8, 0.4)
colnames(eg) <- c('ID', 'type', 'proportion')
eg <- as.data.frame(eg)

# plotting
ggplot (data=eg, aes (x=ID, y=proportion, fill=type)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

It should generate the plot hereabove. In `ID a` for instance, what I am expecting is the blue bar to go to 0.8, but the pink bar to go from 0.0 to 0.7, not be akwardly added on top with no values or grid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that `geom_bar(stat = "identity", ...)` is equivalently expressed `geom_col(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a position argument in `geom_bar` like this:

```
ggplot (data=eg, aes (x=ID, y=proportion, fill=type)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = position_dodge())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with proportion being coerced into a character matrix

```
eg <- matrix(nrow=4, ncol=3)
eg[,1] <- c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b')
eg[,2] <- c('catA', 'catA', 'catB', 'catB')
# this part is the problem
eg[,3] <- c(0.7, 0.3, 0.8, 0.4)
colnames(eg) <- c('ID', 'type', 'proportion')
eg <- as.data.frame(eg)
str(eg)
```

gives

> 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
>
> $ ID        : Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2 1 2
>
> $ type      : Factor w/ 2 levels "catA","catB": 1 1 2 2
>
> $ proportion: Factor w/ 4 levels "0.3","0.4","0.7",..: 3 1 4 2

you need to have it in the correction format:

```
eg <- data.frame(
    ID <- c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b'),
    type <- c('catA', 'catA', 'catB', 'catB'),
    proportion <- c(0.7, 0.3, 0.8, 0.4)
    )

ggplot (data=eg, aes (x=ID, y=proportion, fill=type)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]